# Migrate from logback to log4j2 in application containing dropwizard

Tags: logging, log4j2, logback, dropwizard

I have a java web application that uses dropwizard. Currently, the application is using slf4j with logback implementation for logging. I am trying to move to log4j2 but it looks like dropwizard uses slf4j with logback. How do I use log4j2 and dropwizard without using slf4j2? I want garbage free logging and custom log levels.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with dropdown wizard but the technique should be the same as for any application. Remove the logback jars and replace the with the log4j-slf4j-impl, log4j-api, and log4j-core jars.

Comment: Ah I should've been clearer. I am trying to go for log4j2 without slf4j as I would like to have custom log levels and garbage free logging.

Comment: If you are using third-party libraries and those are using SLF4J changing them would be very difficult. That said, The SLF4J API isn't going to do much when it is bound to Log4j. For most calls it will result in an adapter method just calling the Log4j API method.